# More elegant solution for finding the key for maximum value in the dictionary of degree centrality networkx values?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, networkx

I have a dictionary of degree centrality values with keys, deg_c:

```
{1: 0.026501766784452298,
2: 0.020318021201413426,
3: 0.03356890459363958,
4: 0.019434628975265017,
5: 0.0088339222614841,
...}
```

and I have found the key for maximum value like this

```
def f1():       
   deg_c = nx.degree_centrality(G1)
   degree_value = max([v for k,v in deg_c.items()])
   degree_node = [k for k,v in deg_c.items() if v == degree_value]
   return degree_node[0]
```

it returns the key 105 from the tuple (105, 0.0636042402826855).

however, I'm using list comprehension twice here. how can I write this as one line? there must be a better way..
thanks. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key argument of max.

```
max(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

And to make this faster you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(my_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Comment: @DavidFelipeMedinaMayorga - these answers were posted at about the same time. Yours isn't right... iteritems is for python 2 - and this one has two options. So, they aren't the same.

Comment: how interesting, I did not know about itemgetter(). thanks,Jab!